# Expectation when n items have different probabilities p1, p2, ...., pn

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

> A list contains $n$ items in random order. To find an item in a list,
> the list is searched sequentially until  the  desired  item  is
> found.   What  is  the  expected  number  of  items  searched  before
> the desired item is found if all items are equally likely to be the
> one sought?

I was able to find that the expectation is equal to $(n+1)/2$ in this case.

> If the items are instead requested with known probabilities
> $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$,  suggest a better alternative algorithm and show it has
> a shorter expected number of items searched.

This is where I am struggling right now. I can guess that in this case the expectation would likely be: $\sum x_ip_i$.
But I don't know how I can show that it is a shorter expectation than the one I found in the first part.

Please help me understand that.

Comment: Is there any relationship between $p_i$ and the desires item?

Comment: Thing is that the original algorithm may be good if the item you need to find is chosen randomly (equally likely to be sought). In the second part it is more likely that you’ll need to find one item than another one. For example, imagine that you’ll be always requested to find only the first item (which is still randomly put in the list). How would you proceed?

Comment: **Hint.** Try a simple three-item example, with probabilities $1/2, 1/3, 1/6$.  There are six possible orderings.  Which one is best?  What does that order suggest, in terms of a heuristic?  Then, as @RishiSonthalia suggests, start with that ordering for general $n$, and then show that any swap leads to an expected time that is at least as great.  This establishes that the proposed ordering is optimal.

Comment: @herbsteinberg no i don't think there is any relationship. at least it was not given in the problem

Comment: @BrianTung I did not really understand but I'm guessing the best ordering is the one starting with the item that has the highest probability?

Comment: @DerekKdor: Not just that, but the items are sorted in what order?

Comment: @BrianTung the order where the item with the highest probability comes first

Answer (score 0):

**Indicator variable method:**

Let $X_i$ = $1$ if we end up searching object $i$ and $0$ otherwise. In the initial case it is clear to see , from the uniform indifference, that the probability each object is seen in a search (aside from the object we actually are looking for) is $\frac{1}{2}$. And hence $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{2} $ for $i \not = $ desired object.

You can think of the problem as how many horses finish before a given horse when they all have the same speed.

Let $N$ denote how many objects we search.

The total number of searched objects when looking for object $j$ is $1+ \sum_{i \in [1,n] \setminus j  } X_i$

$N = 1+\sum_{i \in [1,n] \setminus j  } X_i$ and so $\mathbb{E}[N] = 1 + \sum_{i \in [1,n] \setminus j  } \mathbb{E}[X_i] = 1 +\frac{n-1}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2}$ as you already noted.

For you second case we only slightly modify above work. What is the probability we find object $i$ before object $j$ when they have respective probabilities $p_i,p_j?$

$\frac{p_i}{p_i+p_j}$ (condition recursively  on the first searched object)

Can you continue from here?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think I understood your approach. Could you go a little bit further?